# Package organization and project structure design

Tags: java, design-patterns, project

I am trying to create a `textsearcher` library in java, that will have an interface `TextSearcher` and 3 classes implementing it: `RegexPatternSearcher`, `SingleTokenSearcher` and `MultiTokenSearcher`

I then created a `TextSearcherFacade` class that exposes `static` methods like:

1. `static findEmailAddresses(String input)` - uses `RegexPatternSearcher`
2. `static findPhoneNumbers(String input)` - uses `RegexPatternSearcher`
3. `static findDisallowedWords(String input, Set<String> disAllowedWords)` - uses `SingleTokenSearcher`

I want users of the library to have these (i.e. methods from `TextSearcherFacade`) simple methods exposed for ease of use.

However, I don't like the idea of a single `TextSearcherFacade` class with methods that configure and create the `RegexPatternSearcher`, `SingleTokenSearcher` and `MultiTokenSearcher` because these methods depend on different classes and seem logically different.

I am trying to look for a better and more extensible way to design this library. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a class for each of your find methods. For example, you could have an `EmailFinder`, `PhoneNumberFinder`, etc.

Additionally, they could implement an `interface` with a `List<FindResult> find(String input)` method, and you could use them by instantiating them and calling the `find()` method.

Comment: I was thinking of going for that however, phone numbers, email and the ilk all just use regex. So if I do as you say then all these classes would have the same code just different constants. Seems a little frivolous, no?

Comment: @KirtimanSinha, sure, but then so do the methods. I don't think you'd need to write any duplicate logic. Such a class would probably only have a constructor, if it needs to take extra parameters, and a method that returns the result of running the searcher.

Comment: @KirtimanSinha, the advantages however are significant, I think, because if you have classes, you can create new ones in any package (especially if they implement an `interface`) and you can even extend the ones you have in the library. You can do none of that with a single class containing static methods.

Comment: Do you recommend `EmailFinder`, `PhoneNumberFinder` etc. implement a common `interface`? Because if they don't then the users will have to look through the package to find which class they want to use. Simplifying that was the reason why `Facade` class was created.

Comment: @KirtimanSinha, I think there are many advantages of using an `interface`. You could have parts of the code that need a finder, or a list of finders, no matter what they are. IDEs could also help finding all available finders in all packages. Having a common interface will also help guide the creation of new finders.

Comment: I agree with your points. So your recommendation is basically different classes like `EmailFinders`, `PhoneNumberFinders` implementing an `interface` and letting the IDEs do the work of how the users figure out which class to use? I kind of was looking for a good design pattern to use.

Comment: @KirtimanSinha, yes, I think that approach is superior to static methods in a class.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214041/discussion-between-kirtiman-sinha-and-rid).